# How can I access user type from Razor html (Umbraco)

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I use Umbraco and I need to hidden tags for some user roles. 
How can I know user role in view?

Comment: `@User.IsInRole("SomeRole")` ?

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User class has a built in function IsInRole(string roleName).  In your view, you would put something like this:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("myRole")){

    @html.editorfor....
}else{

    @html.hiddenfor...
}
```

Comment: Exactly!
Thank you. It's feature of Umbraco?